# Why am I getting: The type 'IThirdParty' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ThirdPartyAssembly'?

Tags: c#, assembly-references, interface-implementation

Suppose there is third party assembly `ThirdPartyAssembly.dll` that expose following:

```
namespace ThirdPartyAssembly
{
    public interface IThirdParty
    {
        void GetInstance(ThirdPartyInfo info);
    }

    public class ThirdPartyInfo
    {
        public ThirdPartyInfo(string instanceText);
        public string InstanceText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At one of the solution's project `MyAssembly` I refer `ThirdPartyAssembly.dll` and implement following code:

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    public abstract class AbstractMyClass1 : IThirdParty
    {
        void IThirdParty.GetInstance(ThirdPartyInfo info)
        {
            info.InstanceText = "some-text";
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractMyClass1Consumer<T>
        where T : AbstractMyClass1
    {
    }
}
```

At second solution project `MyAssemblyConsumer` I refer `MyAssembly` (as solution project reference) and implement following classed

```
namespace MyAssemblyConsumer
{
    class MyClass1 : AbstractMyClass1
    {
    }

    class MyClass1Consumer : AbstractMyClass1Consumer<MyClass1>
    {
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine so far.
However, when I add `IMyClass2` into `MyAssembly` project that inherits `IThirdParty` interface with following abstract classes

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    public interface IMyClass2 : IThirdParty
    {
    }

    public abstract class AbstractMyClass2 : IMyClass2
    {
        void IThirdParty.GetInstance(ThirdPartyInfo info)
        {
            info.InstanceText = "some-text";
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractMyClass2Consumer<T>
        where T : IMyClass2
    {
    }
}
```

And try to implement following classes into `MyAssemblyConsumer`

```
namespace MyAssemblyConsumer
{
    class MyClass2 : AbstractMyClass2
    {
    }
    class MyClass2Consumer : AbstractMyClass2Consumer<MyClass2>
    {
    }
}
```

I'm getting following compilation error on `MyClass2Consumer`:

*The type 'IThirdParty' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ThirdPartyAssembly'*

The question why I don't need to refer ThirdParty.dll at first case, but need this reference in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in first case you "hide" your reference to `ThirdPartyAssembly.dll`. Yes, your public `AbstractMyClass1` implements `IThirdParty` from it, but it implements it [implicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) so the only way to call `IThirdParty.GetInstance()` method is like this:

```
var myClass1Instance = new MyClass1();
var info = new ThirdPartyInfo(); 

(myClass1Instance as IThirdParty).GetInstance(info); // this can be called
myClass1Instance.GetInstance(info); // <- this method doesn't exists
```

So at compile time of your `MyAssemblyConsumer` project compiler doesn't need to know anything about `IThirdParty`. As you said your first case is compiling successfully, I suppose you don't have any code like this.

In your second case you expose `IThirdParty` of `ThirdPartyAssembly.dll` by your public `IMyClass2` interface. In this case compiler must know about `IThirdParty` interface at compile time (on that line where you defining `AbstractMyClass2Consumer<T>`), that's why you get this exception.

Comment: You are right, at the real code I have for `MyAssemblyConsumer` I do not have any call for `IThirdParty.GetInstance()` - it is actually unit-test that does not have good coverage, I was puzzled with with this compilation error for couple of days.